# Compress git commits

Tags: git

I use git for something it is not intented to, binary files. The project-files are around 80Mb big and the .git-directory, containing 4 commits, adds another 160Mb. There will be many more commits and therefore much more disk space will be needed. Yet, I have another computer with enough disk space and I want to somehow move the repository there.

My first thought was to move the complete repository to the second computer and every time a commit has to be made I move the files between the computers and then make the commit. Given that I won't be making commits all the time this solution is possible, yet tiresome.
My second thought was to create a remote repository, but that does not solve the space-problem.

My newest and very "creative" idea is the following: Create a remote-respository on the second computer and "compress" the commits on the first. Given this commit-history:

```
A <----- B <----- C <----- D
```

Where arrows denote the parent-commit. It should be possible to merge the changes of the first three commits into one. No matter how, by creating a temporary repository and copying the important files into it, somehow it can be done. Then the repository will look like this:

```
A' <----- D
```

For this we had to forcefully set the parent of D from A to A'. But because the parent-commit of D changed I don't think I would be able to push D to the remote repository any more.

To sum it all up: I have a git-repository with big binary files that takes up much space. I want to use the disk-space of another computer, but I have to keep the binary files where they are. To keep it easy, there will be no branching involved.

Comment: May I ask why you are using git? If your squash the commits together you loose the history. If you don't need the history, why do you want to use git? To just copy the files over rsync might be a better idea. If you need the history, do you just keep it on one computer? If so maybe just copy/rsync/... the file to the other computer and do the commit on the computer with enough space.

Comment: @Nef10 I want to squash the commits on the local repository to save disk-space, but on the remote-repository i still want the complete history available. And, since a git-commit is lighter than the sum of all files I asked myself if there is a easy git-way to do things.

Comment: Ok, but why do you want to have git local? Just copy the files over, commit there and only have a repository on remote.

Comment: Consider using something like [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/) or [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/), which allow you to manage a repository with `git` but the *storage* of files separately.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronizing the repo from a machine that has more resources doesn't have to be tiresome. You could automate it.

For example:

- Use `rsync` in a `post-commit` hook to push the changes in the working copy only to the other machine.
- Share the repo (read-only) with the less powerful machine using NFS or a windows network share.